# How can I install java openjdk 8 on High Sierra or newer macOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, install, java, oracle

How do I install OpenJDK 8 on High Sierra or newer macOS?

It looks like support for the Java Oracle JDK version 8 will be deprecated after January 2019 [*Java SE Overview*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html)

Additionally, it looks like publishing and distributing Docker containers with the Oracle Java JDK may not be legal [*Running Java on Docker*](https://blog.takipi.com/running-java-on-docker-youre-breaking-the-law/)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

#### Fastest Solution

Use the [adoptopenjdk cask](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk)

See also https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-install-openjdk-with-brew/712/4

To install latest:

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk
```

To install a specific version

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk9
```

#### Manual Solution

If you are looking to just bring down the binary without actually installing it, simply navigate to https://adoptopenjdk.net

Comment: The cask route didn't actually install the JDK but just downloaded the .pkg file where I had to manually navigate to it and run the installer.

Comment: When I install it this way manually, it asks for a sudo password. This might be the reason it does not work using Ansible.

Comment: brew cask install adoptopenjdk8 no longer works. 
This is the correct path: brew cask install adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8

Answer (score 8):

I found this is the easiest way to download and install. Navigate [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) and choose platform.

Answer (score 8):

Upon running

```
brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

If you get this error

> Error: Unknown command: cask

With the newer versions of brew, cask won't work like this anymore.

Use:

```
brew tap AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk
brew install adoptopenjdk8 --cask
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also install openjdk from Zulu, a commercial vendor that builds and releases OpenJDK [free of charge here](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/)

You can just manually install it from the above link!

Comment: that says "macOS 10.13 or later"